# Translate Timezone name using Timezone JAVA API

Tags: java, timezone

In the following code:

```java
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Locale locale = new Locale("zh","CN");
        TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Chicago");
        String displayNameShort = zone.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT, locale);
        System.out.println("Short time zone name - " + displayNameShort);
        String displayNameLong = zone.getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.LONG, locale);
        System.out.println("Long time zone name - " + displayNameLong);
     }
}
```

```
Output - 
Short time zone name - CDT // Not translated
Long time zone name - 中央夏令时 // Translated
```

I am able to translate the full display name of the timezone but am not able to translate the abbreviation for timezone.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to be a localized version of that short name for `America/Chicago`?

Comment: As a native Chinese speaker, I can't think of any shorter way to say "America/Chicago" than "中央夏令时".

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `TimeZone`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZoneId` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Which short time zone name did you expect in the translation? Asking after @Sweeper’s comment.

Answer (score 3):

## Pseudo time zone names

These 2-4 letter "short time zone" names are not actually [real time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). They are not standardized. They are not even unique!

Examples:

- "CST" = "Central Standard Time" (Americas) *and* "China Standard Time"
- "IST" = "India Standard Time" *and* "Ireland Standard Time"

Since there is no official definition, I do not see how you would expect a localized version.

Stick with using real time zone names in `Continent/Region` format such as `Africa/Tunis`, `America/Chicago`, and `Pacific/Auckland`.

## *java.time* classes: `ZoneId` & `ZoneOffset`

The `TimeZone` class is part of the terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java, such as `Date` & `Calendar`. These were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

The `TimeZone` class was replaced by [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) and [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) classes.

### `TextStyle` with localized `ZoneId#getDisplayName`

The [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) class offers a [`getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale)) method. That method takes an argument for [`TextStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/TextStyle.html), to determine the length or abbreviation.

Let's write code to use each of the six text styles.

```java
System.out.println( "Java version: " + Runtime.version() );
System.out.println(
        "tz database version: " +
                java.time.zone.ZoneRulesProvider
                        .getVersions( "UTC" )
                        .lastEntry()
                        .getKey()
                + "\n"
);

ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" );
Locale locale = Locale.US;  // new Locale( "zh" , "CN" );

for ( TextStyle textStyle : TextStyle.values() ) {
    String output = zoneId.getDisplayName( textStyle , locale );
    System.out.println( "output for " + textStyle + " = " + output );
}
```

When run.

```
Java version: 17+35-2724
tz database version: 2021a

output for FULL = 北美中部时间
output for FULL_STANDALONE = 北美中部时间
output for SHORT = CT
output for SHORT_STANDALONE = CT
output for NARROW = America/Chicago
output for NARROW_STANDALONE = CT
```

When run for [`Locale.US`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html#US).

```
Java version: 17+35-2724
tz database version: 2021a

output for FULL = Central Time
output for FULL_STANDALONE = Central Time
output for SHORT = CT
output for SHORT_STANDALONE = CT
output for NARROW = America/Chicago
output for NARROW_STANDALONE = CT
```

### `FormatStyle` with `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`

And let's try some code using the time zones in action with a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Here we use a `DateTimeFormatter` from `ofLocalizedDateTime` to automatically localize our generated text. This class takes an argument of `FormatStyle` (not to be confused with the `TextStyle` we saw above) to determine length versus abbreviation. So we loop all four enum objects of `FormatStyle`: `FULL`, `LONG`, `MEDIUM`, & `SHORT`.

```java
Locale locale = new Locale( "zh" , "CN" );
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) );

for ( FormatStyle formatStyle : FormatStyle.values() ) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( formatStyle ).withLocale( locale );
    String output = zonedDateTime.format( formatter );
    System.out.println( "output for FormatStyle " + formatStyle + " = " + output );
}
```

When run.

```
output for FormatStyle FULL = 2021年8月9日星期一 北美中部夏令时间 上午12:19:42
output for FormatStyle LONG = 2021年8月9日 CDT 上午12:19:42
output for FormatStyle MEDIUM = 2021年8月9日 上午12:19:42
output for FormatStyle SHORT = 2021/8/9 上午12:19
```

And when run for `Locale.US`.

```
output for FormatStyle FULL = Monday, August 9, 2021 at 12:20:40 AM Central Daylight Time
output for FormatStyle LONG = August 9, 2021 at 12:20:40 AM CDT
output for FormatStyle MEDIUM = Aug 9, 2021, 12:20:40 AM
output for FormatStyle SHORT = 8/9/21, 12:20 AM
```

We can see that, for both locales, the `LONG` format style uses `CDT` as the unofficial short name of the time zone.

---

Lastly, again, I recommend you avoid using these 2-4 letter pseudo zone names wherever practical. And when exchanging date-time data as text, never localize; always use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for data-exchange.

Answer (score 0):

CDT stands for Central Daylight Time.

I guess it don't translate the Shortcut (since not all languages uses letters to write).